# Split JavaScript Into Small Parts To Add To An Array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

So, I am working on a text-based Javascript/HTML game where the character has an 'inventory' of things they have found throughout the game (Money, Food, Water etc.). It is not going to be a short game, so i would like to have a way for the player to be able to start where they left off. Also, I would like to do this WITHOUT PHP/MySQL or any language but HTML/JavaScript. So my idea was this: Say a character was at a location in the game with the code 2918, they had 0129 dollars, 0004 'water', 0029 'food', these values would then be stored in one string (2918012900040029) when they save, and they would need to keep this code and enter it next time they load the game. Here's where I'm stuck. When they enter the code next time they play, I would like to take the string of numbers, break it up every four letters, and store each chunk in an array. Any ideas for getting this to work?

Comment: I'll try to trim it :|

Comment: TL;DR; there was really nothing wrong with your post except "thanks" and "TL;DR" comment that just does not add anything to the problem. Side notes: consider encrypting the string (even base64 would be enough), consider offering to mail code with "mailto" or at least using local storage to remember the state if player using the same browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so if you're just looking for how to split your string into groups of 4 characters and put em in an array you could just use a regular expression and String.match();

[This is the regular expression](http://regexr.com/3bnr0) that matches groups of 4 characters

```js
var str = '2918012900040029';
var strArray = str.match(/(.){4}/g);

//prints '["2918", "0129", "0004", "0029"]'
console.log(strArray); 

//Alternatively your could use substr() and split it manually or with some looping 
var str = '2918012900040029';
var strArray = [str.substr(0,3),
                str.substr(4,7),
                str.substr(8,11),
                str.substr(11,15)];
```

Comment: I don't totally understand your example, my apologies, I am not very advanced, nor do I know JQuery.

Comment: Yeah the Jquery isn't really important its just so your can run it and see. The important part is just Stringify and Parse. Unless your more interested in how to save the string in the browser?

Comment: Okay. Now, I wanted to be able to split the string every 4 characters or so, and put them into an array, I'm not sure what the function of this code is.

Comment: @DamianSilva Sorry about that I re-read your question and thought you were asking something totally different :) I've update my answer.

Comment: No problem! I'm beginning to understand it now, my only question is, when you use the line "var strArray = str.match(/(.){4}/g);" What exactly is this doing? Is this splitting the string into bits of four and putting them into an array? If so, would "alert(strArray[0]);" alert "2918"?

Comment: Yep your correct on both counts. Regular expressions look pretty cryptic. You use them to search for patterns in strings. Usually for me I just use trial and error and lots of google to figure out how to make em do what I need. That site I linked in my answer is really good at showing you how they will work. String.match() just takes a regular expression and puts every substring that matches the pattern into an array. Here are a few links: [string.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match),[RegExp](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Comment: Final note: `/(.){4}/g` is just shorthand for this `new RegExp("(.){4}","g")`

Answer (score 2):

Using json is definitely an option. However, it sounds like you are interested in building a token that the user can enter that decodes to some given information.

I believe in this case you may be able to make very good use of JWT's

JWT's are encoded strings which once decoded provide a JSON object that can be used for just the purpose you are requesting.

You would want to create the JWT at player sign off and once the player enters their token(If you'd like them to require an extra password that will work easily as well). The token will be decoded and you will be able to work with all of the stored information.

Comment: A great tip, Thank you! But not exactly what I'm looking for. I'll definitely keep this in mind.

Comment: And also, after looking this over, I am a bit confused, could someone give me a small demo on this? Much appreciated.

Comment: @DamianSilva while [JWT](http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-goland-json-web-token-00.html) is probably overkill for basic game I'd strongly recommend some sort of hiding information. Really 129G -> "0129" is just asking for "9999" for every resource counter. Even basic XOR with user name or some other data would make it less obvious.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript cookies. To make a cookie :

```
document.cookie = "location=2918;money=0129;food=0029;water=0004;expires="+expirydate;
```

> Here expirydate is an UTC string, telling when the cookie should get deleted.

To retrieve data of from a cookie :

```
document.cookie
```

This will output this:

```
"location=2918;money=0129;food=0029;water=0004"
```

As you said, you want to store these values to an array then you can use `substr()` to cut this string into pieces.

> Read this for Tutorial on JavaScript Cookies : http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: I considered using cookies, but I would like to keep the use of a 'token', so that saves could be easily 'tweaked'. Good suggestion though!